# How to decrease drop-off rates in mobile surveys

Tags: mobile, surveys, conversion-rate, flow, multiple-data

I am redesigning a survey flow. My product team noticed higher drop-off rates with multiple choice questions – the answers often require the user to scroll, and they can't see all of the options at once. There is no way to avoid it (as far as I know). How might we design long multiple-choice questions to be more user-friendly on mobile, so that we can improve their response rates?

Comment: What makes you think abandonment is related to scrolling? Granted, it could be a factor if you're overwhleming users (simple Hick's Law). But it could be the choices are redundant, or too complex, or scrolling behavior makes the continue button hard to find, or there's not enough motivation to complete the task

Answer (score 1):

There is no great way to solve this issue because, as you mentioned, would have a long list of multiple answers. A possible solution if applicable would be List the 2 or 3 most popular answers and another one entitled “Other”. When tapping “other”, you would extend the list with the remaining options.

Also take into consideration to not list all questions at once but to present them wisely, to avoid choice paralysis as much possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know best practices

But you can inspire in famous applications survey, like Google, Survey Monkey, and trying to understand why users are give up in this question, what are their needs.